# Remove colon from title bar in tcolorbox theorem without a title

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using [the `tcolorbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) (version 2.32, as provided by texlive 2013 on my gentoo linux system) to define a new theorem-like environment for typesetting tasks.

When the title is omitted, the theorem is displayed with a trailing colon in the title bar after the theorem name. See the example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{task}
\tcbmaketheorem{task}{Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{task}{tk}

\begin{document}

\begin{task}[width=3in]{Important homework}{major}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\begin{task}[width=3in]{}{minor}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\end{document}
```

[image: tcbcolorbox theorem without a title]

How can the trailing colon be suppressed from the title bar when no title is given to the theorem?

Comment: I cannot recreate this with version 2.51.

Comment: Neither can I; with the current version the colon is not printed if the title is empty. I suggest you to say `\tcbmaketheorem{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{task}{tk}` so the title bar will have a predetermined height (you see that the heights are different in your example, due to the “p” with a descender in the left box).

Comment: The colon is automatically removed starting from version 2.40. Additionally, theorems can now be created with the more powerful new macro `\newtcbtheorem` with automatic numbering. For your example with egreg's addition, this would be `\newtcbtheorem{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{tk}`. Numbering can be influenced by options, e.g. `\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{tk}` numbers within sections. More options are given in the documentation.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I would suggest to turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow the suggestion of Daniel and turn my comment into an answer. The simple answer (as already given by the other comments) is to update `tcolorbox` to the recent version `2.51`; this solves the original problem. Additionally, my suggestion is to exchange `\tcbmaketheorem` by the more powerful macro `\newtcbtheorem`. With it, the MWE of the question gets a tick easier since no counter `task` has to be created by hand:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}% version 2.51 (2013/09/16)
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{tk}

\begin{document}

\begin{task}[width=3in]{Important homework}{major}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\begin{task}[width=3in]{}{minor}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another advantage of `\newtcbtheorem` is that you can easily add chapter or section numbers. Of course, you could achieve this also by altering the number output with the known `LaTeX` mechanisms, but now it is again a tick easier as the following example shows using `number within=section`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}% version 2.51 (2013/09/16)
\usepackage{lipsum,amssymb}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries,colframe=red!50!black}{tk}

\begin{document}
\section{Just a Test}

\begin{task}{Important homework}{major}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{task}

\begin{task}{}{minor}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{task}

\begin{task}[separator sign dash]{Another separator}{some}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{task}

\begin{task}[separator sign={\ $\blacktriangleright$}]{Yet another separator}{other}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{task}

\end{document}
```

[image]