# Automatically generate fitted pdfs

Tags: pdftex, links, crop, pdfcrop

I'm writing some kind of a notebook using LaTex. I'd like to have basically one page for each note, the page being fitted to the text of the note. For the moment I'm using a very long page by default, generate the pdfs using pdflatex, and then crop them using pdfcrop, and finally merge them using gs. Everything runs fine, but the links inside the cropped pdfs are broken.

Can I generate fitted pdf directly from pdflatex? Otherwise, can I crop the pdfs and preserve the links? Thanks!

Comment: Try this implementation of a pdf cropping script: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259

Comment: You could use the standalone package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next code was taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138610/1952) and slightly modified adding `multi=task, border=2mm` options.

It uses `standalone` class as `cropping` tool and `tcolorbox` to produce notes (task in this case).

```
\documentclass[multi=task,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}% version 2.51 (2013/09/16)
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem{task}{\strut Task}{fonttitle=\bfseries}{tk}

\begin{document}

\begin{task}[width=3in]{Important homework}{major}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\begin{task}[width=5in]{}{minor}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{task}

\end{document}
```

This code produces a pdf file with to pages like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! One issue however is that my notes are not LaTeX environments like the newtcbtheorem in your example. So apparently standalone doesn't seem to understand that it needs to crop the file. Do you see any solution? Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin Please read page 9 from `standalone` documentation. You need to fix some `environment` to be cropped. But it can be something like `\newenvironment{note}{}{}`. If you could post some example with your notes ...

Comment: Thanks Ignasi. Finally I created an environment for my notes, now it works just perfectly. Thanks again!