# Automatically generating variable page sizes for each item in an enumeration

Tags: enumerate, standalone

I want to take an enumerated list and make each item a different page.  The height of the page should scale so that it's tight around the text.  The width should be left alone.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item lots of text here that will make up the first page.

\item different amount of text here that will make up the second page.  

\item page 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I've seen this example: 
[Automatically generate fitted pdfs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218206/automatically-generate-fitted-pdfs)
which is almost what I need.  But I want it to be done within \item rather than creating a new environment.  Ultimately I actually want each page to be a different pdf file.

Comment: What is the point of putting it all in an enumerate environment when each 'item' is in fact not in an environment at all, but needs to be put on a separate page? Do you just want each 'item' to be numbered?

Comment: So much for semantic markup...!

Comment: Partly because I want it numbered, and partly because I'm given it in that format and I need it in that format for some other uses.  I'd rather have a couple files that input a single file than have to maintain several files that have different formatting.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  I'm pretty sure LaTeX can do it.  See the link I gave.  Perhaps we're talking about different things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[multi=myenum,border=2mm,varwidth=4in]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\arabic*,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}[series=myenum]
  \item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item
\end{myenum}

\begin{myenum}[myenum]
  \item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item
\end{myenum}

\begin{myenum}[myenum]
  \item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item This is some item
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `pdftk` to get different pdfs for different pages.